# (ASP.NET MVC5) How do files should be saved? In SQL Server database or server folder, which solution is better with these case?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

How should files be saved? In SQL Server database or server folder, which solution is better with these case?

Which is better in these case?

1. Profile image
2. File Storage
3. Image data (in user's Message, Email...)

Comment: Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748/storing-images-in-db-yea-or-nay) hope it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i assume you refer to SQL file stream technology ( BLOB) vs SMB  (Server Message Block ) server folder...

here is a good article you can refer
http://www.webdevdesigns.com/newsroom/blob-vs-file-system/

in short , if my most used file size is small , i will prefer SQL . But let say i want to store video or may be file size which is average 50MB or above , i will prefer file server.

in practical, you will want to use visual studio debugger and run several test to confirm actual processing time because other factor will come in , eg your SQL server and file server performance may not equal...or ... Your application server was also same role as your file server  which mean data packet need not send via network and have a good I\O.